# Python Mocking for unit testing using Py.Test

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

```
class TestHBVbs3(object):
      @patch.object(Hbvbs3, 'GetConfigClass')
      def test_get_grower_list(self, config_data, mock_requests_get):
          # Arrange
          config_data.return_value = ConfigMock()
          post_response = {'1st_key': '1st_value', '2nd_key': '2nd_Value'}
          mock_requests_get.return_value = MagicMock(status_code=200, post_response=post_response)

          # Act
          sut = Hbvbs3()
          the_response = sut.get_growers_list()

          # Assert
          assert_equals(the_response.response["1st_key"], mock_requests_get.return_value.response["1st_key"])
          assert_equals(the_response.response["2nd_key"], mock_requests_get.return_value.response["2nd_key"])
          assert_equals(the_response.response, mock_requests_get.return_value.response)
          assert_equals(the_response.status_code, mock_requests_get.return_value.status_code)

Actual code in hbvbs3.py:
class Hbvbs3(object):
        _logger = log.logging.getLogger("Hbvbs3")

    def get_growers_list(self):
            dbconfig = GetConfigClass()
```

My Issue:
I could not figure out how to successfully use the annotation to mock this:     *@patch.object(Hbvbs3, 'GetConfigClass')* # This piece of code does NOT work.
I had to eventually just put the GetConfigClass instantiation into a utility method and mock that call, but was hoping that I could get help with actually mocking this specific instantiation in the method itself: "get_growers_list(self):" ...
- How does one successfully mock this sort of instantiation inside an instance method of my class Hbvbs3 using the mock annotations?
I tried all sorts of combinations in the annotation such as:

```
@patch('Hbvbs3.GetConfigClass')
@patch.object(Hbvbs3, '__main__.GetConfigClass')
@patchHbvbs3('_get_growers_list.GetConfigClass')
```

None of these worked, so is there a way to simply Mock this sort of instantiation using annotations in python? This doesn't seem that hard, but I'll be danged if I can find the right combination to the annotation.
Please let me know where I'm going wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code for the file `hbvbs3.py` has this kind of import statement at the top:

```
from config import GetConfigClass
```

... and the `GetConfigClass` is used as you've shown inside `Hbvbs3`. Therefore to replace `GetConfigClass` with a `Mock` instance, you can use the decorator form of `patch`:

```
@patch('[...].hbvbsp3.GetConfigClass')
```

You need to ensure that the path used is the full path to the `hbvbsp3` module (replace the `[...]` - I usually use the full python path from the root of the project for clarity). I've always found the docs on [Where to patch](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#where-to-patch) useful.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this and let you know if it works. I appreciate the help!